# How to identify button click event of template page in view page of django?

Tags: python, django

i am doing a small project in django by using python.

In that project, there is a table with list of pending task having columns: task_id,summary,description,due_date.

I have to give 'edit' button in each row so that one can edit the data of that particular row. But I am not able to identify the button click event in view page for the particular row.
Please somebody help me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not talking about browser click events since you're tagging this with `python` and `django` only.

You can identify which `<input type="submit">` element was pressed by giving it a `name`.

A user clicking on `<input type="submit" value="edit" name="summary" />` will be identified by the presence of a `summary` key in `request.POST`

```
# form snippet
<input type="submit" value="Edit Summary" name="summary" />
<input type="submit" value="Edit Due Date" name="due_date" />

# view snippet
if request.POST.get('summary'):
    print('user clicked summary')
elif request.POST.get('due_date'):
    print('user clicked due date')
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for answering..I have tried with this method..but probs is that how to identify the particular row. Each row edit button has edit name..so..??

Comment: @Ravi - that's up to you.. The easiest way would be to make each row a unique form with a hidden input called `row` with the row number on it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my answer (an example) if you want to use "GET" instead of "POST". 
Assuming that you want to  get a value from the user input in html textbox whenever the user clicks 'edit' button, and then call a python function (mypythonfunction) that you wrote inside mypythoncode.py. Note that "btn" class is defined in a css file.

inside yourtemplate.html:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="text" value="8" name="mytextbox" size="1"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="edit" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

inside view.py:

```
import mypythoncode

def mymethod(request):
  if(request.GET.get('mybtn')):
    mypythoncode.mypythonfunction( int(request.GET.get('mytextbox')) )
return render_to_response('App/yourtemplate.html')
```